# Extrair .zip com status

Tags: c#, progress-bar, arquivo-zip

Como extair arquivos .zip de uma maneira que eu possa ver os status dos itens que estão sendo extraídos.

Ex:

```
static string GetStatus() { return "Extraindo... " + current_arquivo; }
```

Usando o sistema OpenSource do Ionic.Zip [Ionic.Zip no codeplex](http://goo.gl/tfkMEu)

Answer (score 1):

Acho que pode usa da seguinte maneira:
Dentro do ForEach você Terá cada Arquivo..

```
private void MyExtract()
{
  string zipToUnpack = "C1P3SML.zip";
  string unpackDirectory = "Extracted Files";
  using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack))
  {
      // here, we extract every entry, but we could extract conditionally
      // based on entry name, size, date, checkbox status, etc.  
      foreach (ZipEntry e in zip1)
      {
        e.Extract(unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
      }
   }
}
```

Clique [Mais Referências](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples)